# How to append text to all values of javascript Array

Tags: javascript

Basically, I need to convert a string

```
"23423,1616,3461743,1345"
```

to a string

```
"<img src='23423'></img><img src='1616'></img><img src='3461743'></img><img src='1345'></img>
```

So far I have tried:

```
    var PhotoArray=JSONeventobject.Events[i].FileNameArray.split(","); // Just convert this string to array

    for (i = 0; i < PhotoArray.length; i++) {
        PhotoArray[i] = "<img src='"+PhotoArray[i]+"</img>";
    }


            var Photostring = PhotoArray.toString().replace(",", "")
```

But this causes my browser to crash. It makes sense to me :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you close your image tag. Another thing that may cause the problem is that `i` is undefined. Does your browser give an error message?

```
var str = "23423,1616,3461743,1345";
var PhotoArray = str.split(",");
for ( var i = 0; i < PhotoArray.length; i++ ) {
    PhotoArray[i] = "<img src=\"" + PhotoArray[i] + "\"></img>";
}
str = PhotoArray.join("");
```

Comment: The end tag for image elements is forbidden.

Answer (score 18):

Some terrible answers here. Try:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(",").map(function(a) { return "<foo>" + a + "</foo>"; }).join("");
```

Or with slightly more modern Javascript:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(",").map(a => `<foo>${a}</foo>`).join("");
```

Also please be aware of [HTML injection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an `</img>` tag in HTML, so you don't need that.

In  `PhotoArray[i] = "<img src='"+PhotoArray[i]+"</img>";` you're not ending the image tag, this will produce `<img src='1616</img>` which is why it gives strange results. Try   `PhotoArray[i] = "<img src='"+PhotoArray[i]+"'>";` instead.

Comment: How ? What browser ? Can you put a repro on jsfiddle so we can see ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a loop (and I didn't want to use a loop), you could do this:

```
var str = "23423,1616,3461743,1345";

str = ("," + str + ",").split(',').join("'></img>,<img src='").split(",").slice(1,-1).join('');

console.log(str);
```

What it's doing is adding a comma on either side of the list, splitting the string into an array based on those commas, then adding the img tags on either side with the join call, splitting again based on the command between opening img tag and closing img tag we just put in, burning the first and last elements in the array, and then finally joining them all back together into a single string.

The console output is:

```
<img src='23423'></img><imgsrc='1616'></img><img src='3461743'></img><img src='1345'></img>
```

Nothing like an ugly one line solution!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @mikel says --

You're using the same variable, `i`, as your index into `JSONeventobject.Events` and as your index into `PhotoArray`. Without seeing the rest of your code, I don't know whether that's going to be a problem, but it's worth checking.

Also, rather than converting to an array and back, it seems simpler to just write:

```
var Photostring = "<img src='" + JSONeventobject.Events[i].FileNameArray.replace(/,/g, "'/><img src='") + "'/>";
```

(that is, replace all the commas with `'/><img src='`, prefix the first element's `<img src='`, and append the last element's `'/>`).

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable '`i`' declared as `var`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#1    str.split([separator[, limit]])
```

split function
splits a string into an array
based on separator we give. limit is optional.

```
#2    arr.map(callback[, thisArg])
```

map function
returns new array
that is formed
from result of
calling "callback" function
for each element in "arr".
thisArg is optional.

```
#1    str.split([separator[, limit]])
```

join function
joins all elements of an array, into a string. limit is optional.

So, answer is:

```
var photoString = "23423,1616,3461743,1345";
var photoArray = str.split(",").map(
    function(a) {
        return '<img src="' + a + '"></img>';
    }
).join("");
```

Sources:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join